# Install gdal extention in GeoServer2.12.1

Tags: geoserver, gdal, extensions

I am trying to install the GDAL extension.I need to use ecw files in GeoServer.I want to see more rasters formats display.I was trying to follow this guide http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html, but it's not really clear for me.....
I have completed this steps

1)Download the GDAL extension for this version and extracted to 
C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.12.1\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib

2)Download the GDAL 'CRS definitions' for your imageio-ext version
create 'GDAL_DATA' as environment variable and populate it
C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.12.1\GDAL_DATA

3) Download the native libraries for windows populate it
C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.12.1\gdal-1.9.2-MSVC2010-x64

After that i am confuse how i will do?

Comment: what do you see listed as raster stores now?

Comment: @Thanks  Ian Turton. It is not showing more rasters formats  ....

Comment: then one of the previous steps failed look in the log file to see which

Comment: @ Ian Turtion, will you please show me one demo for GDAL extension then its really helpful for me..